# Why do all my 16.04 servers in VirtualBox have the same IP address (10.0.2.15)?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, nat

On half a dozen separate 16.04.3 servers, all running NAT for the network connection, when I run `ipconfig` I get back `10.0.2.15` as the address for each machine.

[image: apadter settings]

Each machine *should* be getting a DHCP address on the VirtualBox private network - right - so shouldn't they all be different?

[image: ifconfig for enp0s3]

Comment: I assume virtualbox makes a separate NAT for each machine?

Comment: @ByteCommander - thanks for the push in the right direction

Comment: This would appear to be troubleshooting a Mac application rather than anything about Ubuntu.

Comment: @drkokandy :: it turned out to be a VirtualBox question (***not*** a "Mac application"). But appeared to be an Ubuntu question when I asked it.

Comment: ...and the downvote is for?

Comment: I mean sure, a Mac implementation of a crossplatform application, but it's comprarable in my mind to using this site to try to troubleshoot Firefox on Windows... Virtualbox specific troubleshooting has been ruled off topic in the past.

Comment: @drkokandy :: there was no way of knowing it was application-specific when asked. Had an issue with Ubuntu not recognizing more than one NIC, too - happened to be in VirtualBox, but the answer I found (on AskUbuntu) cane from a physical box solution. But thanks for insulting my intelligence along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@[Byte Commander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander) pushed me in the right direction with his comment.

When using *NAT*, [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html) hides all other connections except the virtualized "single" address for that one server. So it's a single, isolated network that *happens* to be "the same" for all VMs.

You need to create a NAT Network in Preferences to group VMs together.

[image: Network preferences for VirtualBox]
<sup><sub>VirtualBox preferences panel</sub></sup>
[image: add new NAT Network]
<sup><sub>create a new NAT Network</sub></sup>

And you need to connect the VM to that NAT Network (by name) vs just NAT.

[image: VM network connection]
<sup><sub>pick the named NAT Network</sub></sup>